# Why does MS SQL Server Management Studio almost freeze up my computer while it restores?

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-management-studio

Why does MS SQL Server Management Studio almost freeze up my computer while it restores?  It makes it so when I click on the clock it takes seconds for the calendar to open.   I don't see why this should be since I have 4 gigs of ram and a dual core CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I used to see this behaviour a lot too.

For me I believe it was because I was I/O bound on my system drive. I moved the .mdfs and .ldfs off my system drive onto a secondary drive and this stopped the machine freezing up during restores.

Answer (score 0):

Are you restoring to a database on your computer? Perhaps you are I/O bound.

Before starting the restore fire up Task Manager and keep an eye on Memory and Proc usage. If running Vista or Windows 7 start up the Resource Monitor instead. That will easily tell you where the bottleneck is when a restore is running.

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess but I would expect the Management Studio is trying to reconnect to your database or databases as it thinks that there has been an interruption in the connection, you could try shutting down the Management Studio and then hibernating the computer to see whether this is definitely the problem?